# Having class inside an object

Tags: javascript

I need to have a class inside an object, to be used with **dot notation**. Is it possible?

Are there any other ways to achieve the same result?

Example:

```js
const Obj {
  
  info(i) { console.log(i); },
  
  class Num {
  
    constructor(n) {
      this.n = n || 5;
    }
    run() {
      console.log(this.n);
    }
  }
}

const n = new Obj.Num();
```

Comment: I don't see why not (although I don't think your syntax is correct) - JS "classes" are basically just syntactic sugar for functions, and there's no reason not to have a function inside an object, of course. I'm curious what you're trying to achieve with this, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just set a key for it

```js
const Obj = {
  info(i) { console.log(i); },
  Num: class { // or Num: Class Num

    constructor(n) {
      this.n = n || 5;
    }
    run() {
      console.log(this.n);
    }
  }
}


const n = new Obj.Num();
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Great. Is it possible to have `num: Class Num` and then `const n = new Obj.num();`?? I need a lower case initial letter for the object property. It is possible with `Obj.num = Num;`

Comment: @erosman yes, you can name the property whatever you like `num: class { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

Yeah it's strange but possible.

```
const Obj = {
  info(i) { console.log(i); },
}


class Num {

  constructor(n) {
    this.n = n || 5;
  }
  run() {
    console.log(this.n);
  }
}

Obj.Num = Num;

const n = new Obj.Num();
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Maybe not so strange as we do this a lot when using node modules.